# How to give variable arguments to `makeprg`

Tags: vim, parameter-passing, keymapping

I have a build script "maker", which I intend to set as makeprg. The script takes two arguments: `flag_verbose` and `flag_install`, the former suggests whether to give verbose output(for each program) the later causes the installation if build were successful.

Now I wish to set a few key mappings like:
`<F7-(a/d/j/z/i)> :make <return> :copen`
here I want to carry an argument to maker script. The `flag_verbose` and `flag_install` consist of single character from(a[apt}/d[x]/j[avac]/z[all]) and 'i[nstall]' respectively.

So basically I want to give different arguments to the script depending on `<FN-x>` keystrokes, x being different flags.
Can I set such a functionality in vimrc or a vimscript? If so , how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no `<F7-a>` notation, and you cannot define a mapping that gets triggered by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> simultaneously. What you can do is map the *sequence*, written as `<F7>a`.

So, you could define the following set of mappings:

```
nnoremap <F7>a :make a<CR>:copen<CR>
nnoremap <F7>d :make d<CR>:copen<CR>
...
```

This can be simplified via *metaprogramming*:

```
for s:arg in ['a', 'd', 'j', 'z', 'i']
    execute printf('nnoremap <F7>%s :make a<CR>:copen<CR>', s:arg)
endfor
```

But I would instead opt for this solution, which prepares the incomplete command-line and positions the cursor at the position where the arguments will be placed. With this, you only have a single mapping, and have the possibility to also pass no or multiple arguments. The downside is that you have to also press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch the command:

```
noremap <F7> :execute 'make '<Bar>copen'<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

Comment: here, if I do :make [myArgs], will the myArgs be passes to the maker script?
actually that's where I got confused. Thanks for the second solution, it solves the problem in one line, gives choice for input, as well as  it's more efficient than for loop!

Comment: Yes, they will be passed, assuming you have something like `:set makeprg=maker`. You can also specify where the arguments will be placed via `$*`; see `:help :make_makeprg`.

Comment: shouldn't there be a `:` before `copen` here ? or its not needed because of that `:execute` command ? also , Can <Left>... sequence be replaced by `8h` or `8<Left>` for simplicity?

Comment: The `:execute` is needed because otherwise `:make` would eat all arguments. As we're in Ex mode already, no `:` is needed. And no, there's no shortening of `<Left>` possible here.

Comment: that `'` after `make` causes "trailing characters" error after script completes. Otherwise it works as expected. Also I have following line in my vimrc `autocmd Filetype java set makeprg="maker"` but I need to manually set makeprg every time, otherwise shell interprets arguments as separate commands. Any guidelines for that please.

Comment: Edit: removed quotesmarks around  `maker` , and it seemed to fix the `makeprg` issue.